# Apache 2.4 ProxyPassMatch Redirect 301 issue

Tags: php, apache, redirect

redirection 301 in virtualhost nor .htaccess not working for php files.

My environment:
 apache 2.4
 php-fpm 7.0

My vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxx@example.com
    DocumentRoot /pathto/www/
    DirectoryIndex index.htm index.php index.html
    ServerName www.example.com

    <Directory "/pathto/www/">
        RewriteEngine on
        Redirect 301 /myfile.php "http://www.example.com/page"
        Redirect 301 /contact "http://www.example.com/contacts.htm"

        Include /pathto/www/.htaccess
    </Directory>

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/pathto/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

Redirect 301 /file.php is also in .htaccess, but no one is working.
All others redirect rules bases on uri or alias work fine !?

Help appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Redirect 301 use mod_alias instead of mod_rewrite, and php files are directly treated by the proxy matching.
The solution is to rewrite the redirection with Rewriterule to be treated by mod_rewrite like this.

```
RewriteRule ^/myfile.php "http://www.example.com/page" [L,R=301]
```

Hope this help